# when i use a wrong way to write useDebounce, but i also get a correct value?? someone know why

Tags: react-hooks, use-state

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y2P5.png)

code like this:

```
import React , { useEffect, useState, useMemo, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import './App.scss';


function debounce(fn, ms) {
  let timer;
  return function(...args) {
   if (timer) {
     clearTimeout(timer)
   } 
   timer = setTimeout(() => {
     fn(...args)
   }, ms);
 }
}

function useDebounce(fn, time) {
  console.log('usedebounce')
  return debounce(fn, time);
}

const App = () => {
 const [counter1, setCounter1] = useState(0);
 const [counter2, setCounter2] = useState(0);

 const handleClick = useDebounce(function() {
  console.count('click1')
  setCounter1(counter1 +1);
 }, 500)

useEffect(function() {
   const t = setInterval(() => {
    setCounter2(x => x + 1)
  }, 500);
  return clearInterval.bind(undefined, t)
}, [])


return <div style={{ padding: 30 }}>
  <button
    onClick={function() {
      handleClick()
    }}
  >click</button>

  <div>{counter1}</div>
  <div>{counter2}</div>
</div>}
```

(1) when i run this code, Counter1 get a correct value(after click ms time => value +1). why a correct value? i mean the value should be click => value +1 not after click ms time => value +1

(2)when i use setCounter(x = > x+1)  to repalce setCounter(counter1+1). the result is after ms timer , console clicked times value. i'm  so  confused

someoen who can told me the reason ? and thanks